# Conditional Root Tag on Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

### My Question

I have a Vue component that renders content like so:

```
<template>

    <div class="item">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ contents }}</p>
        <!-- Lot's of other stuff... -->
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    // export default...
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    // style...
</style>
```

Note the contents **within** the `div`...

In some circumstances, I need to change `<div class="item">` to `<a class="item">`. With that in mind, is there a way to conditionally change the tag (e.g. `a`, `div`) for the root element of a Vue component?

### Research

I have searched around online and was able to find something about using the `render` function like so:

```
render (createElement) {
    return createElement(this.tag, {}, this.$slots.default);
}
```

The issue I have with the above is that it implies that I need two separate components, for example; `Item.vue` and `ItemTag.vue`. Surely there is a way to do this with **one** component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you could use `is`:

```html
<div :is="useA ? 'a' : 'div'">
    ...
</div>
```

This isn't quite what the docs suggests it's for but it does seem to have the desired effect.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is

Using a `render` function instead wouldn't necessarily require you to have two components but it would need you to rewrite your entire template as a `render` function.

Comment: I'll try this now... I did read up on the `:is` condition but I wasn't able to find any docs that hinted it could be used for this. Bear with, I will test now :-D

Comment: This is a cool trick. Given that the docs lead you toward render functions for this sort of problem, I wonder if will actually be supported.